# MySQL Insert statement not executing

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run an mySQL insert statement like so:

```
function insertAppointment($connection, $id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $phone, $date, $time){

                $sql = "INSERT INTO `appointments` (firstname, lastname, email, phone, app_date, app_time) VALUES ('" . $id . "', '" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "', '" . $email . "', " . $date . ", " . $time . ")";
                $connection->query($sql);

        }
```

$connection is my connection string, which is not the problem. I am able to use it for select statement like so:

```
function getTakenDates($connection){

                $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT app_date, app_time FROM `appointments`");
                $results = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        $results[] = $row;
                }
                return $results;

        }
```

Comment: Error reporting will tell. Is there a specific reason you're not using a prepared statement even though using MySQLi?

Comment: `(firstname, lastname, email, phone, app_date, app_time)` and `($id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $date, $time)`... that can't be right

Comment: MySQLi without parameters kind of defeats the purpose of MySQLi

Comment: `"$connection is my connection string, which is not the problem."` - It might be. Strings don't have a `query` method. Or any method, for that matter.

Comment: `mysqli_query($connection, $sql)` and `$connection->query($sql);` are two very *different* things!  Look at how you are using `$connection` in each case.  What errors are you getting?  I'm sure they'll help you see what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are creating an incorrect query with your $date/$time values:

```
INSERT .... VALUES (..., 2014-11-10, 14:58:00)
```

since your date value is unquoted, you'll actually be trying to insert the result of that math operation (remember `-` is SUBTRACTION if it's not in a string), and 14:58:00 is a totally invalid number - mysql has no idea what those `:` chars are.

You want

```
$sql = "[..snip..]  "', '" . $date . "', '" . $time . "')";    
                        ^-------------^--^-------------^----
```

instead. note the extra quotes. That'll produce

```
INSERT .... VALUES (..., '2014-11-10', '14:58:00')
```